# Cosa significa "bombolo" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-meaning, regional

Nel romanzo *Il sarto della stradalunga*, di Giuseppe Bonaviri, ho letto:

> Luigi sorride, beve un sorso d'acqua da un **bombolo** che teniamo nell'acqua di una secchia arrugginita e si asciuga il sudore che gli bagna le sopracciglia e il collo grasso.

La mia domanda è sul significato del termine "bombolo" che appare in questa frase. Quello che ho trovato nei dizionari che ho consultato (persona di bassa statura e tozza) non ha senso in questo contesto. Si tratta di una parola di origine siciliana?

Comment: Ignoro questa parola, ma dal contesto parrebbe analogo a quello che a Roma viene chiamato “sgommarello”, cioè una specie di ramaiolo con la parte per i liquidi piuttosto capiente, che si usa per trasferire piccole quantità di liquido o per bere direttamente.

Comment: Quasi dimenticavo questo [dizionario etimologico di meridionalismi dell'Università di Nizza](http://www.unice.fr/lirces/langues/real/dialectes/biz.htm) che mi è stato tanto utile anni fa, quando ho cominciato a leggere molti libri di Camilleri.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Penso che si riferisca ad un recipiente per l'acqua definito [bombola](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/bombola/):

> **bómbola** s. f. [affine a bomba2; cfr. il gr. βομβύλη «recipiente»]. –
>   1. **Vaso di metallo o di vetro, lungo e senza collo o con collo corto, in cui si tiene acqua o altri liquidi.** 2. Recipiente cilindrico a
>   fondi emisferici, generalmente di acciaio, per contenere gas compressi
>   o liquefatti: una b. di ossigeno, di metano, di anidride carbonica.
>   Molto diffuse sono oggi le b. spray, o più spesso bombolette spray (v.
>   bomboletta). ◆ Dim. bombolétta (v.), bombolina; accr. bombolóne m.,
>   grossa bombola per installazioni fisse su veicoli stradali o
>   ferroviarî.

In siciliano esiste il [bummolo](https://it.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bummolo):

> Il bummolo o bummulu in lingua siciliana è un contenitore in
>   terracotta utilizzato in Sicilia per mantenere l'acqua sempre fresca
>   anche durante l'estate.
>
> L'utilizzo del bummolo si basa su un comportamento noto dei liquidi
>   che passano allo stato gassoso (evaporazione) mediante assorbimento di
>   calore. Il materiale con cui è costruito il bummolo è permeabile e
>   lascia traspirare continuamente una certa quantità d'acqua che, a
>   contatto con l'aria calda dell'ambiente, si trasforma in vapore.
>   L'assorbimento di calore che ne consegue avviene vicino alla
>   superficie del contenitore che subisce quindi un abbassamento della
>   temperatura sufficiente a mantenere il liquido sempre fresco,
>   addirittura anche se esposto al sole.
>
> Ha origini molto antiche. Ne sono stati rinvenuti esemplari risalenti
>   al XII secolo.

Answer (score 3):

Secondo questo [dizionario etimologico di meridionalismi dell'Università di Nizza](http://www.unice.fr/lirces/langues/real/dialectes/biz.htm) si tratta dell'italianizzazione di un termine
calabro-siciliano di origine greca (< BOMBULOS), anche detto "bombola". Questi autori l'hanno definito così:

> cf. Rohlfs 791 vùmmula / vùmbula, bùmbula "vaso di creta, brocca di acqua col collo stretto", Piccitto I 476 bbùmmula, v. bbùmmulu. (cf. Boerio Bombola 89: "vaso di vetro col collo torto, che serve agli speziali per la distillazione"), Bòmbola "Voce ant. ...dicesi un Vaso o Boccione di vetro corpacciuto, con piede, col collo stretto, che serve ad uso di tenere l'estate vino o acqua nel rinfrescatoio", cf. Rohlfs vùmmulu 791 "orciuolo col collo stretto, vaso di terra", [...], Piccitto I 476 bbùmmulu "Recipiente di terra cotta col collo stretto, poco panciuto, per tenervi l'acqua fresca".

La [bibliografia](http://www.unice.fr/lirces/langues/real/dialectes/annexes/bibliographie.htm) usata è questa:

- BOERIO G., *Dizionario del dialetto veneziano*, Venezia, 1856 [= Martello ed., Milano, edizione anastatica, 1971].
- ‎PICCITTO G., *Vocabolario siciliano*, Centro di Studi Filologici e Linguistici Siciliani, Catania - Palermo, 1977.
- ‎ROHLFS G., *Nuovo Dizionario dialettale della Calabria*, Longo ed., Ravenna, 1977 [: 1990].

Questi sono alcuni utilizzi di "bombolo", "bombola", e anche dei diminutivi "bomboletto" e "bamboletto", e dell'accrescitivo "bombolone" nella letteratura italiana  (ho tradotto i vocaboli in francese):

> BONAVIRI in *Il sarto della stradalunga* 1954 [= Oscar Mobadori 1996]: "Luigi sorride, beve un sorso d'acqua da un bombolo che teniamo nell'acqua di una secchia arrugginita" (p. 27, cf. 3 altre occ.), in *Il fiume di pietra* 1964 [= Oscar Mondadori 1997] (p. 118), in *Notti sull'altura* 1971 [= Oscar Mondadori 1992] (p. 71), in *L'incominciamento* 1983 (p. 114) in *Fiabe siciliane* 1990 (p. 181, cf. n. 1 "Piccola brocca di creta", cf. 1 altra occ.), in *Il vicolo blu* 2003 (p. 134, cf. 2 altre occ., cf. bomboletti, p. 209 e 1 altra occ.); STRATI in *La teda* 1957 (p. 22, cf. 1 altra occ., cf. bamboletto, p. 181, cf. bombola d'acqua", p. 246), in *Tibi e Tascia* 1959 [= Oscar Mondadori 1981]: "prese il bomboletto, se lo mise in testa... se ne andò alla fontana" (p. 18, cf. 85 altre occ., cf. bombolone, p. 18 et 9 altre occ.), in *Il nodo* 1965 [= Oscar Mondadori 1983]: (p. 77, cf. 1 altra occ.), in *Il selvaggio di Santa Venere* 1977 [= Oscar Mondadori 1987] (p. 64, cf. 1 altra occ.); CONSOLO in *La ferita dell'aprile* 1963 [= Einaudi 1977] (p. 40, cf. 2 altre occ.), in *Il sorriso dell'ignoto marinaio* 1976 [= Einaudi 1992] (p. 87), in *Le pietre di Pantalica* 1988 (bombolo, p. 52 et 1 altra occ., bombola p. 75, cf. 2 altre occ.,), in *L'olivo e l'olivastro* 1994 (p. 69); GRASSO in *Nebbie di ddraunàra* 1993 (p. 78); SANTIAPICHI in *Romanzo di un paese* 1995 (p. 55).

I vocaboli ["bùmmolo", "bummoliddru", "bùmmulo" e "bùmmulu"](http://www.unice.fr/lirces/langues/real/dialectes/buatta.htm) sono anche stati usati con lo stesso significato (anche qui ho tradotto qualche parola in francese):

> CAMILLERI in *Un filo di fumo* 1980 [= Sellerio 1998]: "Faceva il vasaio, fabbricava bùmmuli" (p. 23), in *La stagione della caccia* 1992 [= Sellerio 2002]: (p. 125), in *Il birraio di Preston* 1995 [= Sellerio 2000]: "il recinto era stipato di bummola, bummoliddri, quartare, quartareddre, cocò, giarre..." (p. 178), in *Il cane di terracotta* 1996 [= Sellerio 2001]: "A destra, in corrispondenza, un bùmmolo" (p. 121, cf. 15 autres occ.), in *Un mese con Montalbano* 1998 (p. 328), in *Gli arancini di Montalbano* 1999 (p. 194, cf. 5 altre occ., + bùmmulo: 6 occ., bùmmulu: 9 occ., + bummulìddri, p. 201), in *La mossa del cavallo* 1999 [= BUR 2004] (p. 63, cf. 7 altre occ.), in *La gita a Tindari* 2000 (p. 212, cf. 1 altra occ.), in *Il re di Girgenti* 2001 (p. 123, cf. 13 altre occ.), in *La presa di Macallè* 2003 (p. 26, cf. 1 altra occ.), in *La prima indagine di Montalbano* 2004 (p. 40), in *La pensione Eva* 2006 (p. 177); RUSSO in *Nato in Sicilia* 1992 (p. 243, cf. bombola, p. 107); GRASSO in *Nebbie di ddraunàra* 1993 (p. 54), in *L'albero di Giuda* 1997 (p. 234); CONSOLO in (*Di qua dal faro* 1999 (p. 158).

Ecco l'[elenco delle opere letterarie](http://www.unice.fr/lirces/langues/real/dialectes/annexes/bibliographie.htm) citate:

- BONAVIRI G., *Il sarto della stradalunga*, Einaudi ed., Torino, 1954 [= Oscar Mondadori, Milano, 1996].
- BONAVIRI G., *Il fiume di pietra*, Einaudi ed., Torino, 1964 [= Oscar Mondadori 1997].
- BONAVIRI G., *Notti sull'altura*, Rizzoli ed., Milano, 1971 [= Oscar Mondadori 1992].
- BONAVIRI G., *L'incominciamento*, Sellerio editore, La memoria, Palermo, 1983.
- BONAVIRI G., *Fiabe siciliane*, Mondadori ed., Oscar narrativa, Milano, 1990.
- BONAVIRI G., *Il vicolo blu*, Sellerio editore, La memoria, Palermo, 2003.
- CAMILLERI A., *Un filo di fumo*, Garzanti ed., Milano, 1980 [= Sellerio ed., La memoria, 1998].
- CAMILLERI A., *La stagione della caccia*, Sellerio ed., Palermo, 1992 [= Sellerio ed., La memoria, 2002].
- CAMILLERI A., *Il birraio di Preston*, Sellerio ed., Palermo, 1995 [= Sellerio ed. , La memoria, 2000].
- CAMILLERI A., *Il cane di terracotta*, Sellerio edotire, Palermo, 1996 [=Sellerio ed., La memoria, 2001].
- CAMILLERI A., *Un mese con Montalbano*, Mondadori ed., Milano, 1998.
- CAMILLERI A., *Gli arancini di Montalbano*, Mondadori ed., Milano, 1999.
- CAMILLERI A., *La mossa del cavallo*, RCS Libri, Milano, 1999 [= BUR Scrittori contemporanei 2004, 5a ed.].
- CAMILLERI A., *La gita a Tindari*, Sellerio editore, Palermo, 2000.
- CAMILLERI A., *Il re di Girgenti*, Sellerio editore, Palermo, 2001.
- CAMILLERI A., *La presa di Macallè*, Sellerio editore, Palermo, 2003.
- CAMILLERI A., *La prima indagine di Montalbano*, Mondadori ed., Milano, 2004.
- CAMILLERI A., *La pensione Eva*, Mondadori ed., Milano 2006.
- CONSOLO V., *La ferita dell'aprile*, Mondadori ed., Milano, 1963 [= Einaudi, Torino, 1977].
- CONSOLO V., *Il sorriso dell'ignoto marinaio*, Einaudi ed., Torino, 1976 [= Einaudi 1992].
- CONSOLO V., *Le pietre di Pantalica*, Mondadori ed., Milano, 1988.
- CONSOLO V., *L'olivo e l'olivastro*, Mondadori ed., Milano, 1994.
- CONSOLO V., *Di qua dal faro*, Mondadori ed., Milano, 1999.
- GRASSO S., *Nebbie di ddraunàra*, La Tartaruga edizioni, Milano, 1993.
- GRASSO S., *L'albero di Giuda*, Einaudi ed., Torino, 1997.
- SANTIAPICHI S., *Romanzo di un paese*, Rizzoli ed., Milano, 1995.
- STRATI S., *La Teda*, A. Mondadori ed., Milano, 1957.
- STRATI S., *Tibi e Tascia*, A. Mondadori ed., Milano, 1959 [= Oscar Mondadori 1981].
- STRATI S., *Il nodo*, 1965 [= Oscar Mondadori 1983].
- STRATI S., *Il selvaggio di Santa Venere*, A. Mondadori ed., Milano, 1977 [= Oscar Mondadori 1987].